# Click on one specific row from ng-table and load data of that row

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have an ng-table in AngularJS.

```
<table ng-table="fondiTable" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" show-filter="isFiltersVisible">
        <tr ng-repeat="fondo in data | filter:getChiave | filter:getRapporto">  
            <td class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Visualizza</a></li>
                        <li><a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Modifica</a></li>
                        <li class="disabled"><a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Cancella</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Data Rif'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{dataRif: 'text'}" sortable="'dataRif'">{{fondo.dataRif}}</td>
            <td class="i9fontPre text-center" data-title="'Chiave IB'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{chiave: 'text'}" sortable="'chiave'">{{fondo.chiave}}</td>    
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Stato Pratica'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{stato: 'text'}" sortable="'stato'">{{fondo.stato}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Flag S/V'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{fvs: 'text'}" sortable="'fvs'">{{fondo.fvs}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-right" data-title="'Fondo bucket 1 (EUR)'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{fnd1: 'text'}" sortable="'fnd1'">{{fondo.fnd1}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-right" data-title="'Fondo bucket 2 (EUR)'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{fnd2: 'text'}" sortable="'fnd2'">{{fondo.fnd2}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Bucket DH'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{bktDH: 'text'}" >{{fondo.bktDH}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Fondo DH bucket 1'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{fnd1DH: 'text'}" >{{fondo.fnd1DH}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Fondo DH bucket 2'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{fnd2DH: 'text'}" >{{fondo.fnd2DH}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Rapporto'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{rapporto: 'text'}" sortable="'rapporto'">{{fondo.rapporto}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Cdg'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{cdg: 'text'}" sortable="'cdg'">{{fondo.cdg}}</td>
            <td class="i9font text-center" data-title="'Matricola ins'" header-class="'i9header'" filter="{insMatr: 'text'}" sortable="'insMatr'">{{fondo.insMatr}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I would like to select only one row from that table with a simple click on it and show data of that row, not only the ones that I show in the table, but also others referred to my selected row. In a few words, I need a click on one row to show details of that selection.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind ng-click to table row like,

```
<tr ng-repeat="fondo in data | filter:getChiave | filter:getRapporto" ng-click="processData(fondo)"> 
</tr>
```

So on click of each row you will get the corresponding data in controller.

```
.controller('myCntrl',function($scope){
            $scope.processData=function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }

        });
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! It is exatly what I need.